# iOS left side slide menu with partially visiblity

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I want to create a facebook like sliding menu for my iPad application. I have seen many controls at [CocoaControls.com](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=facebook). But almost all them close sliding menu completely when tap on Menu button in navigation bar. I want part of left side menu (only icons) to be visible every time. So that user can tap them without the need of opening side menu. Is there any control available which provides this functionality? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just add a side view with the buttons on the window?...

Comment: If create a side view on window, i still need to create functionality for open/close right panel from scratch. That is why i want to customize any existing open source control.